# How to clear contents of a range in a row, when a specific cell of that row is selected?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table ranging from ("C22:Q26"), where cell ("R22"), ("R23"), ("R24") up to ("R26") are the cells to be selected in a row, to clear contents.

I want to clear contents of a range("C22:Q22"), when cell ("R22") is selected.

Similarly clear contents of a range("C23:Q23"), when cell ("R23") is selected, and so on up to range("C26:Q26") when cell ("R26") is selected.

I wrote this, placed in sheet code.

```vb
Sub clearcontents()
If Range("r22").Selected Then
   Range("R22").Offset(, -15).Resize(, 15).Select
   Range("R22").Offset(, -15).Resize(, 15).clearcontents
ElseIf Range("r23").Selected Then
   Range("R23").Offset(, -15).Resize(, 15).Select
   Range("R23").Offset(, -15).Resize(, 15).clearcontents
ElseIf Range("r24").Selected Then
   Range("R24").Offset(, -15).Resize(, 15).Select
   Range("R24").Offset(, -15).Resize(, 15).clearcontents
ElseIf Range("r25").Selected Then
   Range("R25").Offset(, -15).Resize(, 15).Select
   Range("R25").Offset(, -15).Resize(, 15).clearcontents
ElseIf Range("r26").Selected Then
   Range("R26").Offset(, -15).Resize(, 15).Select
   Range("R26").Offset(, -15).Resize(, 15).clearcontents
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the cells to be cleared automatically? If so, look at the [`Worksheet.SelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) event.

Comment: yes Iplaced this code in worksheet.selectionchange event but still dosent work

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`Worksheet.SelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) event. Add the following code to the *sheet* code module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("R22:R26")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("C" & Target.Row & ":Q" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code is in the 'Worksheet_SelectionChange' macro and it doesn't fire, i would double-check that you have events enabled.

[image]

otherwise this piece of code should do what you want to do, some checks also that the selection needs to be of one cell:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rColumn As Range
  Dim tTable As Range

  Set rColumn = Me.Range("R22:R26")
  Set tTable = Me.Range("C22:Q26")

  If Not Intersect(Target, rColumn) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
      Intersect(Target.EntireRow, tTable).ClearContents
    End If
  End If

End Sub
```